# Search for attribute value in HDF5 database with H5PY

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am using Python to store data in an HDF5 database.

Every data set has a list of attributes associated with it.

I would like to retrieve all data sets that have a given attribute value.

For example, one attribute is `temperature` which could have a value of `20.0`.  I would like to call up all data sets with a `temperature` of `20.0`.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Don't trust float equality comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[fh[i] for i in fh if fh[i].attrs['temperature']==20]]
```

Where `fh` is the hdf file handle.

This will return a list with all such datasets. If you only want their names, use:

```
[i for i in fh if fh[i].attrs['temperature']==20]]
```

Comment: I'll try this out and get back to you.  I'm still learning HDF5.  Thanks very much.